# Is there a di-friendly File management library in Java?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, filesystems

I've used [this library](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html) to work with files, but now I want to write simple unit tests.

Problem: Files class is static final, methods are static and so - are unmockable.
For me it's frustrating, because I now need to actually test the file system and actually test the results, when all I need to do is really just mock methods. Not really unit testing, when you need to actually use the environment.

Example code of the code now:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public void myMethod(File myFile) throws IOException
    {
        Files.move(myFile.toPath(), myFile.toPath(), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
    }
}
```

I would like the code to be likes this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private final Files files;

    public MyClass(Files files)
    {
        this.files = files;
    }

    public void myMethod(File myFile) throws IOException
    {
        this.files.move(myFile.toPath(), myFile.toPath(), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
    }
}
```

So what I need is a class that does the same as "Files" , but is injectable

Comment: Just give it a real `File` and after testing do some cleanup?

Comment: The question title asks for library recommendations, rendering your question off topic. Please consider fixing that.

Comment: What would I change it into? I want for people to recommend me DI friendly file manager. Im not sure what you want me to change to what.

Comment: You could write a thin wrapper around `Files` that is mockable and simply delegates to the static methods of `Files`.

Comment: @DavidConrad yes, that's what I though right away, but I assumed there already is such a wrapper.

Comment: @drakonli Well, there could be, for all I know. Write one and put it on Github, and you can be the savior of the next person that has this problem. :)

Comment: @DavidConrad Yes, indeed I will :) Thank you for understanding, at least)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added a small implementation of what I meant. Now it can be easily injected.
https://github.com/drakonli/jcomponents/tree/master/src/main/java/drakonli/jcomponents/file/manager

```
package drakonli.jcomponents.file.manager;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.CopyOption;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.attribute.FileAttribute;

public class NioFileManager implements IFileManager
{
    @Override
    public Path move(Path source, Path target, CopyOption... options) throws IOException
    {
        return Files.move(source, target, options);
    }

    @Override
    public Path copy(Path source, Path target, CopyOption... options) throws IOException
    {
        return Files.copy(source, target, options);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isSameFile(Path path, Path path2) throws IOException
    {
        return Files.isSameFile(path, path2);
    }

    @Override
    public Path createTempFile(String prefix, String suffix, FileAttribute<?>... attrs) throws IOException
    {
        return Files.createTempFile(prefix, suffix, attrs);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The underlying [`java.nio.Filesystem`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileSystem.html) allows to use an alternative filesystem by implementing a custom [`java.nio.FilesystemProvider`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/spi/FileSystemProvider.html)

Google's [JimFS](https://github.com/google/jimfs) is such an implementation of an InMemory Filesystem that may be well used for testing purposes, as long as you stay away from `java.io.File` classes (which are not supported)

Another option to this would be to use a test harness that operates on your local filesystem such as JUnit 4s `TemporaryFolder` rule

```
@Rule
public TemporaryFolder temp = new TemporaryFolder()
```

You can create files in this folder, test your move operations. The rule ensures the folder is closed after the test is done.

Comment: I'm not sure I explained myself very well. It's important for me to inject and mock the class that works with filesystem. I updated my question, please, have a look.